# A buffer overflow at recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

There is a function `animateTitle()` that changes a browser title periodic - every 3 seconds.

```
var animateTitle = function(countMessages) {
    if (isChatTab) {
        if (animStep) {
            document.title = "New messages ("+countMessages+") - "+origTitle;
        } else {
            document.title = origTitle;
        }
        animStep = !animStep;
    } else {
            document.title = origTitle;
            animStep = false;
    }

    time_title = setInterval(function(){ animateTitle(countMessages) }, 3000);
};
```

In my script the param `countMessages` is changes in realtime and is passed to the function `animateTitle`, so this leads to a buffer overflow, because the function is recursive. How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Since you're not clearing the existing interval every function call is creating new intervals. You should move the interval outside the function:

```
var animateTitle = function(countMessages) {
  if (isChatTab) {
    if (animStep) {
        document.title = "New messages ("+countMessages+") - "+origTitle;
    } else {
        document.title = origTitle;
    }
    animStep = !animStep;
  } else {
        document.title = origTitle;
        animStep = false;
  }
};
 time_title = setInterval(function(){ animateTitle(countMessages) }, 3000);
```

Comment: No, I need call function every 3 second

Comment: @AhmedFaud [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) will call the function every 3 seconds, I think you're confusing it with [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) which will execute only once.